# Msal logout displaying multiple account

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure AD with React JS. When I am signed in using multiple accounts and call msal logout, then it is showing me an option to select an account that needs to be signed out. I just want to show the logout option for the currently active account, rather than all signed-in users.

I have tried to pass an active account using the below snippet but still, I am getting an option to logout all signed-in accounts. Can you please let me know how can I get an option to logout only active account, rather than all signed-in accounts?

```js
const myMsal = new PublicClientApplication(config);

// you can select which account application should sign out
const logoutRequest = {
    account: myMsal.getAccountByHomeId(homeAccountId)
}

myMsal.logoutRedirect(logoutRequest);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript2#sign-out-with-a-redirect

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Prompt-less Logout](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/logout.md#promptless-logout):

```
const currentAccount = msalInstance.getAccountByHomeId(homeAccountId);
// The account's ID Token must contain the login_hint optional claim to avoid the account picker
await msalInstance.logoutRedirect({ account: currentAccount});
```

You will need to add **login_hint** claim to token optional claims in your application's **Token configuration** on Azure Portal:

[image]

Comment: what's the homeAccountId value?

Comment: @Ziko sorry, I just copied that from docs, but I didn't use this method, What I used was: this.msalService.logoutPopup({ account: this.msalService.instance.getActiveAccount() }) for logout.

But please do NOT forget to add login_hint claim to token optional claims, as mentioned above.

Comment: @Ziko You will need to set active account in login, before using that in logout, to do so, I used this:
this.msalService.loginPopup({ prompt: "login", scopes: [] })
      .subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
        this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
       // rest of login code here...
});

Answer (score 0):

> msal logout it is shows  an option to select an account that
> needs to be signed out

**The logout prompt you're seeing comes from the AAD service, because it needs to know which user to terminate the session for on the authentication server side**

Unfortunately, this is a known issue with the AAD service. At this time, there is no way to bypass the logout account selection screen on logout

According to this  document : https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/logout.md and code descriptions, **MSAL is clear the cache and session data on the client side (browser)**

There is github issue  you can refer it for more details :

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2922